# C# SqlCeConnection not updating .sdf file, no data in the file

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, sqlconnection

I have the following code:

```
string dbfile = "C:\\Users\\Ralph\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\WorksTimes\\WorksTimes\\Database.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);
        connection.Open();

        DataSet data = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table2");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        data.Tables.Add(dt);

        SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from [Table2]", connection);

        if (data != null && data.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test");

            DataRow dr = data.Tables["Table2"].NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 0;
            dr["Name"] = "Jan";
            data.Tables["Table2"].Rows.Add(dr);

            data.Tables["Table2"].Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Jan" });
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.Tables["Table2"].Rows.Count);//returns 2
            adapter.Fill(data);
            adapter.Update(data);
            connection.Close();
        }
```

When I check the database file its still empty.
Why isn't the code adding rows to my database file?

Comment: I actually don't see _any_ insert operation to your .sdf file. You just filling a `DataSet`.

Comment: @SonerGönül doesnt the adapter.Update add the data to the .sdf file? I dont know that much about this, i'm just learning it. Any tips would be helpfull.

Comment: As a extra side note: you only close your connection inside the if statement, while opening it outside. This can leave you with an open connection while your not using it anymore (and causes a exception if you try to open it again, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx InvalidOperationException)

Comment: @marc_s - really? I thought [DbDataAdapter.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.update.aspx) executes "the respective INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements".

Answer (score 0):

The Update command will update existing rows - but you seem to try to insert new rows which would be the task of the .Insert method (not the .Update() ) .... –  marc_s 16 mins ago

Thanks, it looks like I was using the wrong things to try to do get the rows in my database.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure why your code does not throw an exception and just silently does nothing.

The following is an example of how I would probably do it. I tested it and the data ends up in the *.sdf.

```
string dbfile = yourDbFile;
using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile))
{
    using (var adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from [Table2]", connection))
    {
        using (var builder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(adapter))
        {
            // The CommandBuilder automatically builds INSERT, UPDATE 
            // and DELETE statements from the given SELECT statement.
            // otherwise, these commands would need to be specified
            // manually.
            builder.RefreshSchema();

            using (var data = new DataSet())
            {
                // Fill() opens the connection if necessary
                adapter.Fill(data); 

                // The "table", i.e. the result of the select statement,
                // does *not* have the name "Table2".
                // To reduce confusion, just work with the "table"
                // at index 0.
                var dr = data.Tables[0].NewRow();
                dr["ID"] = 0;
                dr["Name"] = "Jan";
                data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);

                data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Jan" });
                adapter.Update(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- Use `using` when dealing with objects that implement `IDisposable`.
- Use a `CommandBuilder` to automatically build INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements from the SELECT statement, or create the respective commands manually.
- The `Fill()` (and `Update()`) method automatically opens the connection if necessary. You don't need to open the connection manually.
- You should *not* expect to be able to access the returned data via the tablename. Access it via the index to be sure.

You might want to read up on the [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/at8a576f.aspx) method for further information.